# Image gets push down from the grid, I have tried to put margin-top: -20px but doesn't work

Tags: css

Image gets push down/ slips from the grid, I have tried to put `margin-top: -20px`, `position: relative` in css, but it doesn't change. Also I have tried added `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for

tag under `.popularArea > div > p`  but still it displays const myData = Test text in the grid. Could someone please advise ?
JS filddle:
note: I am unable to add html tags on this rendered html output from react markdown..

https://jsfiddle.net/1w5cex6r/17/

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(232, 236, 250);
}

.trendingArea {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(450px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 25px !important;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px !important;
  border-color: #E2E8F0;
}

.popularArea {
  display: flex;
  height: 230px;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px !important;
}

.dataDate.tags.readmoreLink.views {
  columns: 2 auto;
}

.popularArea p img {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -2% !important;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.popularArea div p {
  width: 100%;
  color: rgb(92, 90, 90);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.popularArea div h3 {
  width: 450px;
  color: rgb(6, 6, 6) !important;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.popularArea div h5,
h6 {
  width: 450px;
  color: rgb(6, 6, 6) !important;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="trendingArea">
    <a href="https://google.com">
      <div class="popularArea">
        <div class="dataDate renderElipsis tags readmoreLink views">
          <h5>22 Feb 2023</h5>
          <h6>cypress</h6>
          <p>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
          </p>
          <h3>Main Header text here</h3>
          <p>Best heading added here.The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Print the whole text here. Ideas are always usefull....</p>
          <p>
            <code>const myData = Test</code>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, preferably as a [MCVE]. Don't make us go off site to have to help you

Comment: I have added JS Fiddle for reference in the question. Will add the code to the question block again.

Comment: @JonP I have added now, please have a look !

Comment: Are you wanting to display the image on the left and the text on the right?

Comment: Yes image on the left side and text on the right side

Comment: Sometimes in the process of answering a question, I go way overboard. Then another answer gets accepted before I can post it, leaving me with some code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/OJoNpWx?editors=1100). Why? Too much `!important`, hardcoded sizes, line-clamp not working, odd structure. Anyway, use it or ignore it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML you have text elements above and below the image. If you want the image and the text to flow how you want you are best off refactoring the HTML and let things flow as naturally as possible instead of working against the natrual flow.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(232, 236, 250);
}

.trendingArea {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(450px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 25px;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-color: #E2E8F0;
}

.popularArea {
  display: flex;
  height: 230px;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.dataDate.tags.readmoreLink.views {
  columns: 2 auto;
}

/*Note the p selector has been removed*/
.popularArea img {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.popularArea div p {
  width: 100%;
  color: rgb(92, 90, 90);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.popularArea div h3 {
  width: 450px;
  color: rgb(6, 6, 6) !important;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.popularArea div h5,
h6 {
  width: 450px;
  color: rgb(6, 6, 6);
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="trendingArea">
    <a href="https://google.com">
      <div class="popularArea">
        <div class="dataDate renderElipsis tags readmoreLink views">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
          <h5>22 Feb 2023</h5>
          <h6>cypress</h6>
          <h3>Main Header text here</h3>
          <p>Best heading added here.The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Print the whole text here. Ideas are always usefull....</p>
          <p>
            <code>const myData = Test</code>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

On a side note you really should avoid using `!important`.